# How can I compare two lists with xunit test

Tags: c#, list, unit-testing, xunit

I am currently trying to compare two lists, with the same items in it, with xUnit but getting an error while running.

```
Assert.Equal(expectedList, actualList);
```

Error:

```
"Assert.Equal() Failure"
Expected: List<myObject> [myObject { modifier = '+', name = "name", type = "string" }, myObject { modifier = '+', name = "age", type = "int" }]
Actual:   List<myObject> [myObject { modifier = '+', name = "name", type = "string" }, myObject { modifier = '+', name = "age", type = "int" }]
```

Comment: are you getting a run time error or the assert is failing?

Comment: when I run the unit test, I'm getting the assert failing message.

Comment: It doesn't know how to compare two `myObject` objects

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This has to do with object equality.

`MyObject` does not implement the `Equals method`. By default you get a reference equality. I assume you have two different objects for `MyObject`.

Meaning it does not matter that your List holds the similar object(meaning with same values) they are not of the same **reference**, so your test checks that, this is why it *fails*.

```
internal class MyObject
{
    {
        public char Modifier { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Type { get; set; }

    }
}


            [Fact]
            public void ListMyObject()
            {
                var list1 = new List<MyObject>
                {
                    new MyObject{ }
                };
                var list2 = new List<MyObject>
                {
                    new MyObject{ }
                };

                Assert.Equal(list1, list2); // Fails
            }
```

When we update our class to this.

```
internal class MyObject
    {
        public char Modifier { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Type { get; set; }
        //When i add this to my class.
        public override bool Equals(object obj)
        {
            return this.Name == ((MyObject)obj).Name;
        }
    }
```

Also as mentioned in the comments by Jonathon Chase.

It is a good idea to `override` the `GetHashCode()` method as well. It is preferred to inherit from `IEquatable<T>` so you can avoid casting.

Everything goes green.

```
        [Fact]
        public void ListMyObject()
        {
            var list1 = new List<MyObject>
            {
                new MyObject{ Name = "H" }
            };
            var list2 = new List<MyObject>
            {
                new MyObject{ Name = "H" }
            };

            Assert.Equal(list1, list2); //Passes
        }
```

Comment: Thank you so much! There was my problem, was using the default Equal method. I just have overriden it now, also added **&& this.type == ((myObject)obj).type && this.modifier == ((myObject)obj).modifier** and it works fine.

Comment: You must also override `GetHashCode` when you override the `Equals` method for types. You should also check for type symmetry when doing equality. It's also a good idea to go ahead and implement `IEquatable<T>` while you're at it.

Comment: @JonathonChase i am not familiar with what you are refering. Why? -> you must also override `GetHashCode`

Comment: @panoskarajohn [Refer to this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/371328/why-is-it-important-to-override-gethashcode-when-equals-method-is-overridden)