# How to check equality of items of two list using Assert in Nunit

Tags: c#, .net-core, nunit, assert

I'm fairly new to unit testing. The following code is just for reference.
I want to check empId of list one is same as the emp id of list 2 or not.

```cs
public class EmpInfo
{    
    public EmpInfo( string lastName,string firstName, string empId)
    {
        EAlphabeticLastName = lastName;
        EFirstName = firstName;
        EmpId = empId;
    }
}

[Test]
[Category("Explicit")]
public void testEmp() 
{
    public List<EmpInfo> List1e = new List<EmpInfo>(){        
            new EmpInfo("dx","Tex","25")  
    };

    public List<EmpInfo> List2e = new List<EmpInfo>(){          
            new EmpInfo("dx","Tex","25")  
    };
    Assert.AreEqual(List1e.empId,List2e.empId);
}
```

What is the correct way to check equality of list items in Nunit (C#) ?

Comment: `Assert.AreEqual(List1e.empId,List2e.empId);` this won't compile... Also try to format your code better

Comment: thanks @VidmantasBlazevicius but i have already tried this but not working.

Comment: Can you explain what do you want to test? The list has no empId, but items have... what behavior you expect here? That the first list should have a set of items with the empId of second one?

Comment: @M_P as it is already mentioned you need to to set which one you need to check in the list use sth like this `List1e[0].empId` or elaborate your logic so we can provide more. If you want to know more about object equality you can take a look here -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59458136/how-can-i-compare-two-lists-with-xunit-test/59458398#59458398

Answer (score 1):

You may have to override the `Equals` and `GetHashCode` method in the class `EmpInfo` and write the compare logic .

Use the above methods to check whether all the objects in one list are present in another .

Comment: It is also a good idea to inherit from the IEquateable -> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.iequatable-1?view=netframework-4.8

Answer (score 1):

Alternatives to checking that the list contains only items with the same ID:

1. Implement equality for the `EmpInfo` class, as suggested by User965207, either by overriding `Equals` or implementing the `IEquatable` interface. NUnit will use either one if present. If you don't have control over the code of the system under test, this is of course not available to you.
2. Use a `Select` statement to create a new list for  comparison, as suggested by Sean. You actually only need to do this for the **actual** value being tested. Your **expected** value can just be a list or array of empids in the first place. This approach only requires changing the test code.
3. Use NUnit's `List` class to do essentially the same as option 2 for you...

   Assert.That(List.Map(List1e).Property("empid"), 
       Is.EqualTo(new [] {"empid1", "empid2" /*etc*/}));

   Since you have not provided a full implementation of `EmpInfo`, I made the assumption that `empid` is a property. If it's a field, this won't work.

I realize I haven't added a lot to the prior answers here, but I thought a summary of the possible approaches with pros and cons would be of help.

Answer (score 1):

There are numerous ways to achieve it

1. Use https://fluentassertions.com/objectgraphs/ (The easiest and fastest way)

```
    List1e.Should().BeEquivalentTo(List2e);
```

2. Move all the individual comparisons to the `.Equals` method (Or implement `IEqualityComparer`)
3. Build a helper method that iterates through public properties by reflection and assert each property

```
      public static void PropertyValuesAreEquals(object actual, object expected)   {
        PropertyInfo[] properties = expected.GetType().GetProperties();
        foreach (PropertyInfo property in properties)
        {
            object expectedValue = property.GetValue(expected, null);
            object actualValue = property.GetValue(actual, null);
          if (!Equals(expectedValue, actualValue))
                Assert.Fail("Property {0}.{1} does not match. Expected: {2} but was: {3}", property.DeclaringType.Name, property.Name, expectedValue, actualValue);
          //……………………………….
        }
```

4. Use JSON to compare the object’s data

```
    public static void AreEqualByJson(object expected, object actual)
    {
       var serializer = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
       var expectedJson = serializer.Serialize(expected);
       var actualJson = serializer.Serialize(actual);
       Assert.AreEqual(expectedJson, actualJson);
    }
```

5. Use [Property Constraints](https://nunit.org/docs/2.6.4/propertyConstraint.html) (NUnit 2.4.2)

Answer (score 0):

How about `Assert.IsTrue(List1e.SequenceEqual(List2e))`

Comment: don't want to check sequence i want to check one particular item.

Comment: Ah, ok. Then you would want `Assert.IsTrue(List1e.Select(x => x.empId).SequenceEqual(List2e.Select(x => x.empId))`

So, quick explanation - `Select` creates a list of the `empId`s for each object. So we create a list of the `empIds` for each list, and then compare those lists with `SequenceEqual`.